# Flash Animation Action Script 2.0

Tags: actionscript-2

I am facing issue regarding Flash animation,
I am new to action scripting.

```
on (rollOver){
    gotoAndPlay(2);
}
```

Once mouse over,start animation and complete its loop and stop.
and mouse over should be disable while it complete its loop (300 frames),
if then mouse over happen it should be started again from frame 2.
There are one movie clip and movie clip imported into one scene.
I am using action script 2.0

Answer (score 0):

```
on(rollOver){
    if(_currentframe < 1 && _currentframe > 300){
        gotoAndPlay(2);
    }
}
```

As long as the current frame is LESS than 1, meaning if it's 0, and at the same time, if the current frame is GREATER than 300, only then should it `gotoAndPlay(2);`. This is assuming that your last frame of animation is at 301 -- if it's NOT, and is rather on 300, then change `_currentframe > 300` to `_currentframe > 299`